# MOIP consumir Json Web Api MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

Estou precisando utilizar a [API de pagamentos do Moip](http://dev.moip.com.br/referencia-api/) como forma de pagamento do meu sistema, como faço para fazer o request via `json`?

**Documentação**

```
Consultar cliente GET

Por meio desta API é possível consultar as informações e detalhes de um cliente.

ENDPOINT GET https://sandbox.moip.com.br/v2/customers/{customer_id}

EXEMPLO GET https://sandbox.moip.com.br/v2/customers/CUS-Y6L4AGQN8HKQ
```

**REQUEST**:

```
Content-Type: application/json

Authorization: "Basic MDEwMTAxMDEwMTAxMDEwMTAxMDEwMTAxMDEwMTAxMDE6QUJBQkFCQUJBQkFCQUJBQkFCQUJBQkFCQUJBQkFCQUJBQkFCQUJBQg=="
```

**RESPONSE**:

```
200 (OK)
Content-Type: application/json

 {
  "id": "CUS-Y6L4AGQN8HKQ",
  "ownId": "meu_id_sandbox_1231234",
  "fullname": "Jose Silva",
  "createdAt": "2015-01-14T11:28:22-0200",
  "birthDate": "1988-12-30T00:00:00-0200",
  "email": "jose_silva0@email.com",
  "phone": {
    "countryCode": "55",
    "areaCode": "11",
    "number": "66778899"
  },
  "taxDocument": {
    "type": "CPF",
    "number": "22222222222"
  },
  "shippingAddress": {
    "zipCode": "01234000",
    "street": "Avenida Faria Lima",
    "streetNumber": "2927",
    "complement": "8",
    "city": "Sao Paulo",
    "district": "Itaim",
    "state": "SP",
    "country": "BRA"
  },
  "moipAccount": {
    "id": "MPA-M1M01PACC0NT"
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "https://sandbox.moip.com.br/v2/customers/CUS-Y6L4AGQN8HKQ"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Eu a usei à alguns anos, tanto que comecei a converter um SDK dele para C#. Segue abaixo o repositório. Você pode forkar, melhorar e ajudar a contribuir para que ele fiquei bacana. [MoipSDK.NET](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/76574)

Comment: Você está querendo fazer esta requisição via HTTP com c#? é isso?

Comment: Sim. GET , POST, PUT e DELETE via json para requisição MOIP

Answer (score 1):

Tem biblioteca pronta para isso: [WirecardCSharp](https://github.com/matmiranda/WirecardCSharp).

Exemplo de como consultar um cliente:

```
var result = await WC.Customer.Consult("CUS-XXXXXXXXXXXX");
```